# Count number of dots in character string with str_count?

Tags: r

I am trying to count the number of dots in a character string.

I have tried to use `str_count` but it gives me the number of letters of the string instead.

```
ex_str <- "This.is.a.string" 
str_count(ex_str, '.')
nchar(ex_str)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` is a special `regex` symbol, so you need to escape it:

```
str_count(ex_str, '\\.')
# [1] 3
```

Using just base R you could do:

```
nchar(gsub("[^.]", "", ex_str))
```

Using `stringi`:

```
stri_count_fixed(ex_str, '.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `base R` solution could be:

```
length(grepRaw(".", ex_str, fixed = TRUE, all = TRUE))

[1] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use the base function `gregexpr`:

```
sum(gregexpr(".", ex_str, fixed=TRUE)[[1]] > 0)
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stringr::str_count` with a `fixed(...)` argument to avoid treating it as a regular expression:

```
str_count(ex_str, fixed('.'))
```

See the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/QX7rFJ):

```
library(stringr)
ex_str <- "This.is.a.string" 
str_count(ex_str, fixed('.'))
## => [1] 3
```